# Refreshing Activity ,activity is starting from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, refresh

I have a fragment class which starts another activity when list item is clicked.

```
   Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),SResponses.class);
   startActivity(in);
```

this activity has a handler which refresh the activity after few seconds .

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         finish();
                         startActivity(getIntent());
                     }
                 }, 4000);
```

But when once this class is opened it keep on refreshing all the time even when I press the back button it don't go back and and it keep on refreshing again and again.I want to only run this handler when this activity is active.

Comment: why do you "refresh" your data by destroying the current activity and create new one?

Comment: actually my database is updating time to time and values are updating in the list and i want to update the list with new values after certain time.

Comment: how could i know when the database is going to update?

Comment: Can't you use something like SimpleCursorAdapter and call notifyDataSetChange() every time the database is updated?

Comment: Where that database is stored? On the device? And how it is updated?

Comment: db is on the phone and it is updated as the message is received in Service running .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very strange approach for me to "refresh" activity like that but you can try something like this:

1) declare class members:

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
                     finish();
                     startActivity(getIntent());
    }
}
```

2) set handler:

```
handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 4000);
```

3) and `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` call `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

Comment: Thanks but I strongly recommend that you will look for better solution to refresh activity. CursorAdapter and ContentProvider should be a good soultion

Comment: ok I'll do it with some other way but after tomorrow because I have a final year project presentation tomorrow  :(

Comment: Doesn't it will be more slower to update the list every time rather than refreshing? because updating the list every time involves accessing the DB.

Comment: First of all what you do is not refreshing, you recreate activity which involves inflating layouts etc, besides when you recreate activity you have to access db as well to populate listview.